# Why would you use a void pointer in this code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *pc; 
    int *pi;
    double *pd;

    pc = (char *)10000;         
    pi = (int *)10000;          
    pd = (double *)10000;           
    // 1)
    cout << "before pc = " << (void *)pc << " pi = " << pi << " pd = " << pd << endl;

    pc++;
    pi++;
    pd++;
    // 2)
    cout << "after increase pc = " <<  (void *)pc << " pi = " << pi << " pd = " << pd << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this code(1, 2), why is variable `pc` cast to a void pointer?

I am checking that a run-time error does not occur if you do not print the variable `pc`.

Comment: -1 You were able to easily test behavior without cast and see result. In other words, don't ask immediately.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Because `char*` when printed using `cout << something` will try to print a string (`cout << "Hello, World" << endl;` uses `char *` [pedantically, in this example, a `const char *`] to represent the `"Hello, World"`).

Since you don't want to print a string at address 10000 (it would MOST LIKELY crash), the code needs to do something to avoid the pointer being used as a string.

So by casting to `void*` you get the actual address printed, which is the default for pointer types in general, EXCEPT `char *`.

Answer (score 38):

Because otherwise, the overloaded `operator << (std::ostream&, const char*)` would be called, which doesn't print an address, but a C-string.

For example:

```
std::cout << "Boo!";
```

prints `Boo!`, whereas

```
std::cout << (void*)"Boo!";
```

prints the address that string literal is located at.

Comment: Nitpick: the actual overload for C-style strings is a non-member operator function template.

Comment: @T.C. yes, never said it was a member ;)

Comment: But the non-member version would have two parameters :)